# Проблема c map.js

Tags: sourcemap

На сайте имеется файл
shop.js.map
также на сайте имется файл shop.js, в котором хранится код в сжатом виде, наверное это должен быть shop.min.js файл.

Через консоль shop.js.map можно открыть, как webpack каталог и лазать по файлам, то есть сам код тоже сохранен в shop.js.map.
Но если удалить его, то сайт будет работать в прежнем виде, то есть map.js файл не нужен, как я понял. Тем более я глянул код, и он устаревший. С тех пор в shop.js файл много чего добавилось и в shop.js.map обновлений не добавлялось.

Задача состоит в том, что мне нужно в удобной форме работать с shop.js файлом, не со сжатым, а нормальным, развернутым файлом, и упаковывать его обратно при сохранении. Потому что работать со сжатым файлом и вносить в него нормальные обновления невозможно!

Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
{
"version":3,
"sources": [...],
"names":["...",...],
"mappings":["...",...],
"file": "shop.js",
"sourceContent":[" \t// The module cache\n..."],
"sourceRoot": ""
}
```

Содержимое shop.js.map файла